# Covering a circle using rectangles

Tags: geometry, circles, pi, rectangles

What is the **maximum area** that can be covered with $3$ rectangles inside
a **radius $1$ circle**?(i.e. maximum area $=\pi$) The rectangles can be **any length and height you want**, and **can rotate and reflect**.

(I found a solution which is $1.5\sqrt{3}$,
which is to make a **hexagon shape **outline)

Bonus: Proof why this shape you found is the **largest possible**, and is the answer  related to those questions which **allows more rectangles** in the circle(e.g. you can put $4$ inside.)

Bonus 2: Does your method also work on ANY
four-sided shapes(like a kite)?
Thanks!

Comment: you mean radius 1? As the max area is $\pi$, the radius is 1.

Comment: Yes, it is the same as saying radius 1.

Comment: I think you should also specify that the rectangles are not overlapping.

Comment: Apparently, the answer for three *squares* in a unit circle is unknown (or at any rate not proved): https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/squincir/

Comment: @Notwen They can overlap, so I didn't state it out.

Answer (score 6):

By using a hexagonal pattern but offsetting the corners, we can slightly increase the area. If the short sides of the rectangles are all $x<1$, we have:
$$A = 3x\sqrt{4-x^{2}}-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}x^2$$
$$\frac{dA}{dx}=0\Rightarrow x=\sqrt{2-2\sqrt{\frac{3}{7}}}\approx 0.8311\Rightarrow \boxed{A=3\sqrt{7}-3\sqrt{3}}\approx 2.7411$$

[image]

Comment: Can you proof that this is the largest among them all? Thanks.